# How can i read data of outh user in firebase database?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an android app in which when the user create its account as a technician his name id display in a `listview` in which other users which don't have `firebase` outh.the problem is that I am unable to show data of technicians in the `listview`.

This is my `firebase` database

[image]

This is my code that return 0 items or blank `listview`. I tried several things, but unable to display the information of technicians. Anyone please help me with this I am new in `firebase`.

```
    public class Technician extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> tecnames = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_technician);

        ImageButton Back_Btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);
        Back_Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Technician.this, Technician_main.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(Technician.this, Book_Now.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        Technician.CostumAdapter costumAdapter = new Technician.CostumAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(costumAdapter);
        GetItems();
    }

    private class CostumAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tecnames.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cuctom_listview, null);

            TextView txt_one = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.skill_txt);
            txt_one.setText(tecnames.get(i));
            return view;
        }

    }

    private void GetItems() {
        DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.child("user");
        final Query itemsQuery = ref.orderByChild("name");

        itemsQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Pojo item = singleSnapshot.getValue(Pojo.class);
                        tecnames.add(String.valueOf(item));
                        Log.e(TAG,"value of name"+itemsQuery);
                    }
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        Log.e(TAG, "Returning " + tecnames.size() + " items");

    }
}
```

Comment: did you tried to notify adapter about data change inside your firebase event listener.

Comment: Also you are returning null in getItem of your adapter. Is your log statement inside firebase listener printing ?

Comment: yes i think so..

Comment: acctually i dont know can you guide me whats wrong

Comment: no my firebase listener is returning o items

Comment: please help me to fix it

Comment: [How to refresh Android listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2250770/2754146)

Comment: @UmarHussain anything??

Comment: Check if tecnames has data after calling GetItems(); Print its size in Log (tecnames.size())

Comment: no it dont have any

Comment: yes  the size of tecnames is 0

Comment: you are retrieve data from class POJO and then adding in arraylist<String>, shouldnt this be of type <POJO> .. @Ehtishamhabib

Comment: @PeterHaddad oh you deleted that post -_-

Comment: @Shruti will undelete :p

Comment: @Ehtishamhabib did you try that?

Comment: yes i am trying

Comment: @Shruti i follow all the steps you tell me but i am going nowhere

Comment: @Ehtishamhabib in your code you have R.layout.cuctom_listview, is this the right name?

Comment: its my costum listview name

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
  Technician.CostumAdapter costumAdapter = new Technician.CostumAdapter();
```

Write this:

```
 Technician.CostumAdapter costumAdapter = new Technician.CostumAdapter(getApplicationContext(),tecnames);
```

Then add this constructor inside of the class:

```
private ArrayList<String> datas;
Context mContext;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> datas) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_item, datas);
    this.mContext=context;
    this.datas = datas;

}
```

change `addListenerforSingleValueEvent` to `addValueEventListener`

Comment: datas @Ehtishamhabib

Comment: i dont know y but i am unable to solve this issue Context mContext;
        public CostumAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> datas) {
            super(context, R.layout.activity_technician, datas);
            this.mContext=context;
            this.data = datas;

Comment: i am receiving error in { super(context, R.layout.activity_technician, datas);

Comment: @Ehtishamhabib `R.layout.cuctom_listview`, id of your list item layout not activity

Comment: would you please give me a favour and give me your skype id so i can share you my code

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are few things that you need to fix:

1.Your array list tecnames should be of your POJO class

`ArrayList<POJO> tecnames = new ArrayList<>();`

Now change `tecnames.add(String.valueOf(item));` to `tecnames.add(item);`

2.As @Peter Haddad suggested, you need to give this list to your adapter as a dataset.

3.Firebase DB listeners are asynchronous so you need to notify your adapter after you get data in your dataset(list). Add the following code inside `onDataChange` after your foreach loop:

`costumAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46926544/7382665) for the 3rd point.